# how to find the boundaries (End point) of table in current viewport?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

my requirement is, when the table width is more than current viewport then have to add two buttons namely left and right. when the user clicks on the left button table has to move left side likewise right.

so i have decided to jQuery animation method to complete the requirement. My challenge here is, i could fond the left boundary but not the right one. please suggest me your view and points

```
var width = window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth|| document.body.clientWidth;

var tableWidth = jQuery("table").width();

var annimwidth = tableWidth - width;

jQuery(".leftButton").on("click", function()){

$("table").animate({
    marginLeft: '-='+annimwidth+'px'
});
if(jQuery("table").css("margin-left")==0){
disable the left button
}
}
```

likewise how to disable the right side.

right side the margin property varies as per the table width. so margin property is not a right way to go.

help me how to stop or disable the right button

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to find the boundaries. You just need to do a little scrollLeft animation each time you press the left or right arrows.

Something like this:

```
function scrollH() {
  if (this.className == 'left')
    $('.viewport').animate({
      scrollLeft: "-=" + 50
    }, 150);
  else
    $('.viewport').animate({
      scrollLeft: "+=" + 50
    }, 150);

}
```

If the element is already scrolled to its edge jQuery won't animate anything.

I made a little fiddle to show the concept. https://jsfiddle.net/z5vgq3hr/37/

Tell me if it works for you.